# @PrePersist/@PreUpdate called when entity is loaded from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Current setup: Hibernate 4.3.6, Wildfly 8.

I did some migration of my entity relationships, and in order to ensure compatibility with previous data, i use entity listener callbacks to process the new field from the old field.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{

 @NotNull
 @Deprecated
 private String previousField;

 @OneToOne(cascade=ALL)
 private MyNewFieldType newField;

 @PrePersist
 @PreUpdate
 void movePreviousToNewField() {
  this.newField = movePrevious(this.previousField);
 }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class MyOtherEntity{

 @OneToOne(cascade = ALL)
 @NotNull
 private MyEntity myEntity;

}
```

When i do the following:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

....
//This works fine, the @PreUpdate/@PrePersist is not called on the MyEntity
MyOtherEntity entity = em.findEntity(...);

//This on loading the relations, calls @PreUpdate/@PrePersist??
List<MyOtherEntity> entities = em.findEntities(...);
```

For the loading of the list, i get an exception:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing on (MyNewFieldType.id)
```

I am not trying to save anything, i am simply loading the list.

Please note that when i do not have the @PreUpdate/@PrePersist callback, and do the move manually, and then update the entity, everything works fine. The new entity field is cascade persisted as expected.

Comment: Post the full stack trace that is calling PrePersist/PreUpdate (i.e print out 'new Exception()'.printStackTrace() if you don't have an actual exception thrown)

Comment: @maress please post the entity `MyNewFieldType`